# No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'MYAPI' from content with media type 'application/xml'

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, httpclient, xml-serialization

I have my API response like this:

```
<MYAPI xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="MYAPI.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SomeTask LastModified = "Some Date" Resource="Some Resource Name">
       <Name>Some Name</Name>
       <ID>Some ID</ID>  
    </SomeTask>
    ... A lot of these <SomeTask>...</SomeTask> are there    
</MYAPI>
```

I've modeled the class for it as:

```
XmlRoot(ElementName = "MYAPI")]
class MYAPI
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "SomeTask")]
    public List<SomeTask> SomeTask{ get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="SomeTask")]
public class SomeTask {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="LastModified")]
    public string LastModified { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Resource")]
    public string Resource { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm trying to read it like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("MyUsername", "MyPassword");

    var client = new HttpClient(handler);
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://sitename.com:PortNumber/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

    var formatters = new List<MediaTypeFormatter>() 
    {
        new XmlMediaTypeFormatter(){ UseXmlSerializer = true } 
    };

    var myApi = new MYAPI();
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("/api/mysites/tasks").Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {

        myApi = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MYAPI>(formatters).Result;
    }
}
```

But with this code, I'm always getting this exception:
`No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'MYAPI' from content with media type 'application/xml'.`

Would someone please tell me how to fix this one? Thank You!

Comment: Try making class public maybe so `public class MYAPI`

Comment: Hi CodingYoshi, Thank you for the comment, I tried to make the class public, but I got new exception now:
`SerializationException: Error in line 1 position 106. Expecting element 'MYAPI' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MYAPIAgent.ResponseModels.SomeTasks'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'MYAPI', namespace ''.`

Comment: Thank You CodingYoshi, That solved my problem. and as for the newer exception, I had forgotten putting `formatters` parameter.